# Uncheck checkbox on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to uncheck all the checkbox when callling `location.reload();`, so I used this code, yet the checked checkboxes remain checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `prop()` instead. You also don't need the `each()` loop. `$(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/xuuz5gqn/1/

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
   $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked />Checbox 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked />Checbox 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked />Checbox 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked />Checbox 4<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked />Checbox 5<br/>


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Click on **submit button** checkbox will **unchecked**.

Comment: you are using a submit button which will anyways reset the checkboxes, even without your jquery code

Comment: @KarthikGanesan That's why I called it as an example solution not as a solution.